# Content Security Policy and connect-src when making AJAX POST request in Chrome Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, instagram, content-security-policy

I've used a Chrome Extension to dynamically add a button to the nav bar of an Instagram profile page. When this button is clicked, it makes a POST request using the fetch API to a REST API.

However, when the button is clicked, the fetch fails. I get the console error:

> Refused to connect to 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "connect-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com
>   https://*.www.instagram.com https://graph.instagram.com
>   https://*.graph.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com
>   https://api.instagram.com wss://www.instagram.com
>   wss://edge-chat.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com
>   https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net
>   chrome-extension://my-unique-chrome-extension-id-here".

What do I need to change the content_security_policy to in manifest.json to make AJAX post requests successfully?

```js
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "Content Security Experiment",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Test content security",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.instagram.com/*"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"],
      "css": ["styles.css"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post"
}

// contentScript.js
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("fired");
    addNavBarButton();
};

/**
 * Adds a button to the nav bar of an Instagram profile page. Buggy? Might need a manual reload in browser to get button to appear.
 */
function addNavBarButton() {
    const navBar = document.body.querySelector("div._47KiJ");
    // Create main container div
    const navBarDiv = document.createElement("div");
    navBarDiv.classList.add("Xr0ey");

    // Create the div for the button
    const navBarButton = document.createElement("div");
    navBarButton.classList.add("aButton");
    const buttonText = document.createTextNode("CLICK");
    navBarButton.appendChild(buttonText);
    navBarDiv.appendChild(navBarButton);

    // Add the button to the container div
    navBar.appendChild(navBarDiv);

    // onclick handler
    navBarButton.onclick = buttonClickHandler;
}

function buttonClickHandler() {
    // A Fake Online REST API for Testing and Prototyping - https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#how-to
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            title: 'foo',
            body: 'bar',
            userId: 1
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
        .catch(error => console.log("Something went wrong.", error));
}
```

```css
.aButton {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Instead of content_security_policy add `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/` in "permissions": [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr).

Comment: Works great. Is this intended behaviour? Why is this handled by permissions when you'd expect this to be handled by the content-src directive in content_security_policy, given the error message?

Comment: CSP key in manifest.json is for own pages of an extension.